# How to filter value using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have attached the image:
[image]

From the above image, I have to filter such data "1565158223" and "4" at any place of receiver_id_1, receiver_id_2, sender_id but together.

I want to remove other data which contains "3","1", ect.

I want a solution with minimal code and minimum loops as there are too many records i get it.

I can check the condition like (receiver_id_1 == "1565158223" AND "sender_id" == "4") OR (receiver_id_2 == "1565158223" AND "sender_id" == "4") OR (receiver_id_2 == "1565158223" AND "receiver_id_1 " == "4") Like wise..

But I dont want to write several conditions over here.

Please anybody help me to resolve it.

Comment: check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the features of es6 try this(we suppose your array is `items`):

```
filtered_items = items.filter(item => 
        [1565158223,4].indexOf(parseInt(item['receiver_id_1'])) > -1 && 
        [1565158223, 4].indexOf(parseInt(item['receiver_id_2'])) > -1 &&
        [1565158223, 4].indexOf(parseInt(item['sender_id'])) > -1
        )
```

Notice that it won't change the origin `items` and just `filtered_items` is your final filtered items.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i want that "1565158223" can be """receiver_id_1 ,receiver_id_2,sender_id""" And "4" can be same """"receiver_id_1 ,receiver_id_2,sender_id""".

Comment: Your result will fetch the records for some fix position. If receiver_id_2 has 1565158223 and sender_id has 4 such case also it should work\

Comment: @ShivaniPatel I think I got your desired result. I edited the post. check if and let me know if that is correct

Comment: I have changed your solution a little bit and i get the final result. Thanks!!

Comment: It was my pleasure